# Is returning a Task violating the CQS-principle?

Tags: c#, async-await, command-query-separation

- The CQS-principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) states that a command should return void.
- The recommendation for async methods is to never return void (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), but instead returning a Task.

So, if I write an async command, will that inevitably break the CQS-principle?

Comment: async void still has it's usage in fire and forget scenarios. Where the calling method does not care about the result/when it completes

Comment: @William, I'd say that `async void` has its uses in fire-and-forget scenarios that cannot be easily re-engineered to return `Task`. If you can have it return `Task` and have that task examined for error conditions which are at the very least logged, then it would be an improvement. "Never return void" is good advice, because it's only advice it's not worth following when it's advice it's impossible to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the level of considering what you want to know (a query) or do (a command) then `Task<T>` gives you data and hence is correct for a query and `Task` does not and hence is correct for a command. ("return void" is the language-specific way for some langauges to express "do not return data").

At the level below that, in which you are considering the mechanism by which asynchronous operations are managed, then you always want to have information about the state of the asynchronous operation and so always want some sort of task object. That is not the level to consider command-query separation.

Comparably, if a .NET method called into a COM method it would be calling into code that always returned a value indicating success or failure. That is just an implementation detail of how exception-handling happens in that particular technology. It's either vital or irrelevant to think about this depending on the level you are working at. `Task` is an implementation detail of how task-based asynchronous programming works. It's either vital or irrelevant to think about this depending on the level you are working at.

The level at which you need to think about "is this a command or a query", `Task` is an implementation-detail about how you get `void`.

Answer (score 9):

When dealing with async `Task` represents void and `Task<T>` represents "a result". So no, it does not violate CQS you just need to think of `Task` as `void`.

Answer (score 3):

From the article you are linking:

> When converting from synchronous to asynchronous code, any method
>   returning a type T becomes an async method returning `Task<T>`, and any
>   method returning void becomes an async method returning Task.

Therefore returning `Task` (not `Task<T>`) translates to having a method returning  `void`.